# How are coaxial cable connectors sized?

Tags: connector, coax

I've just tried to crimp 'standard' 5mm TNC and BNC connectors onto a piece of [Aircell 5](http://www.nevadaradio.co.uk/cables-leads-plugs/antenna-cable/ssb-electronic-aircell-5). It didn't fit :-( The outer is far too big for the outer crimp to slide on and the inner is too big to fit in the pin. Bit of a bummer as my plane's now in bits until I fix it.

While I can just get a BNC connector [labelled to be of the right size](http://www.nevadaradio.co.uk/cables-leads-plugs/plugs-adaptors/ssb-electronic-7720) now I realise, where do I start with trying to find a suitable TNC connector? (And actually ideally, I'd rather get a right-angle BNC).

---

*Hmmm. Turns out I'd been sent Aircell 7 instead of Aircell 5. No wponder my 'standard' 5mm connectors wouldn't fit. Nevertheless, question still stands as to what are the important dimensions of coaxial cable and connectors as they're not at all clear.*

Comment: Electronic distributors like Digikey stock many varieties of coax connectors to fit many sizes of cables.

Comment: @PeterBennett, yes but I don't know what parameters I should be searching for. Farnell for example only offer up searching by coax type. Which works unless the particular coax isn't in their list.

Answer (score 1):

There are no 'standard' crimp connectors. Crimp connectors are designed for a specific type of cable, eg RG178. This is why distributors allow you to search by cable type.

Soldered connectors are more forgiving, you can take up more tolerances.

Once you've done your homework, and tabulated the dimensions of all popular cable types (wikipedia 'coaxial cable' is a good place to start, along with cable manufacturer sites), then you can see if the particular cable you have has an equivalent.

It may be better (frequency range permitting) to buy a connector/cable combination you can get, and then splice the cable you have. As a tip, what I often do is to buy a cheap BNC coaxial cable assembly, cut it in half, and then have two 'pre-wired' connectors with coaxial tails. Obviously a coax splice is only going to work well up to some frequency short of the capability of the connectors, but with care it can work surprisingly well.